# CQL select statement return only row key

Tags: cassandra, cql

Column family is

```
create column family markers
with comparator = UTF8Type 
and default_validation_class=UTF8Type 
and key_validation_class=UUIDType 
and column_metadata=
[
 {
  column_name : userid,
  validation_class : UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS
 },
 {
  column_name : activated,
  validation_class : UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS
 },
 {
  column_name : latitude,
  validation_class : DoubleType, index_type: KEYS
 },
 {
  column_name : longtitude,
  validation_class : DoubleType, index_type: KEYS
 },
 {
  column_name : altitude,
  validation_class : DoubleType, index_type: KEYS
 },
 {
  column_name : area,
  validation_class : DoubleType, index_type: KEYS
 },
 {
  column_name : title,
  validation_class : UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS
 },
 {
  column_name : memo,
  validation_class : UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS
 },
 {
  column_name : picdata,
  validation_class : BytesType
 }];
```

When i query ' select * from markers whwere in ([rowkeys]) ' then, result contains only rowkey.

But if i query ' select * from markers ' then result contains all column.

Why if use 'where in ()' , result only rowkey???

I'm sorry for my english..

Someone help me TT

Comment: Can you put up a sample data set and exactly the same query you ran against them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CQL syntax is wrong.

It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM markers WHERE <CLAUSE>;
```

In your example, your  statement of 'in ([rowkeys])' is not valid. I'm surprised it even gives you a result from the misformed CQL statement.

A working query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM markers where latitude > 60.0;
```